# Collection view visible behind navigation bar in iMessage Extension in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, imessage-extension

I'm developing iMessage Extension app.
My problem is that the collection view is visible behind navigation bar(I think navbar is automatically produced by iMessage Extension) in expand mode. 
We can see collectionview (with transparency) behind navbar.
Is there anybody who has experience in this area?
Looking for any help.

Comment: have you set constraint perfectly?

Comment: Yeah, of course, top:0, left:0, right:0, bottom: 0

Comment: try to set navigation nav bar translucent = NO

Comment: Let me know it's working or not

Comment: Try navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false this will fix your problem

Comment: @Joe I tried it for long time ago, It doesn't work for iMessage extension.

Comment: Is ur collectionView programmically  created?

Comment: @Joe no, in storboard, and all constraints are set properly.

Comment: Then it's easy fix. Can you post  your viewDidLoad...

Comment: I have nothing in viewDidLoad,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126395/discussion-between-david-jonker-and-joe).

Answer (score 0):

Referring to @seggy question comment:

> have you set constraint perfectly?

You answered:

> Yeah, of course, top:0, left:0, right:0, bottom: 0

The top constraint should be equals to 64 (it seems the top constraint is between the collectionView and the container view, not between the collectionView and the navigation bar).

Also, you might need to change the bottom constraint's constant value.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

After give Constraints(Top:0,Left:0,Right:0,Bottom:0),you should give Top   Constraints of CollectionView to Top Layout Guide.Bottom ratherthan Superview.Top like this:

CollectionView.Top = Top Layout Guide.Bottom is set to 0.

In viewDidLoad():

```
 CollectionView.frame = view.bounds
 CollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 CollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
 CollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
 CollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
 CollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```